# How to create an instance of a value type "by reference"

Tags: c#, shallow-copy

Consider the code and output:

```
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
    //Where color is from ^ that
    static Color color = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Color otherColor = color;
        color.B = 100;

        Console.WriteLine(otherColor.B);
        Console.WriteLine(color.B);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    //output
    //0   <-- otherColor
    //100 <-- color
```

However, I would like otherColor to carry the same value by reference, such that the output would become

```
//100
//100
```

If possible, how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot do what you want to do, at least, not directly.

The [Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.color.aspx) type is a `struct`. It's a value type. Each instance of `Color` is a separate copy of the value. It is not possible to get two `Color` instances to refer to the same object, any more than it is possible for two `int` instances to refer to the same object.

Now, you might be able to hack something by including the `Color` within your own class. The following has not been tested:

```
public class ColorByReference
{
    Color TheColor {get;set;}
}

static ColorByReference color = new ColorByReference {Color = new Color(0,0,0,0)};
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ColorByReference otherColor = color;
    color.TheColor.B = 100;

    Console.WriteLine(otherColor.TheColor.B);
    Console.WriteLine(color.TheColor.B);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Even for `Color?`  ??

Comment: Any idea for a work around? I am stuck using Color as part of XNA, so I won't be able to make a new class, at least I don't think I can.

Comment: @Colton He just edited his answer with a workaround option. :)

Comment: Awesome, I think I might be able to work with that. Thank you very much. (And yes I tested it and it works.)